# H264 frame viewer

Tags: header, h.264

Do you know any application that will display me all the headers/parameters of a single H264 frame? I don't need to decode it, I just want to see how it is built up.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Three ways come to my mind (if you are looking for something free, otherwise google "h264 analysis" for paid options):

1. Download the [h.264 parser](http://www.w6rz.net/h264_parse.zip) from  (from [this thread](http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-133070.html) @ doom9 forums)
2. Download the [h.264 reference software](http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/)
3. [libh264bitstream](http://h264bitstream.sourceforge.net/) provides h.264 bitstream reading/writing

This should get you started. By the way, the h.264 bitstream is described in Annex. B. in the [ITU specs](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-H.264-200305-S!!PDF-E&type=items).

Answer (score 21):

I've created a Web version - https://mradionov.github.io/h264-bitstream-viewer/

Based on [h264bitstream](https://github.com/aizvorski/h264bitstream) and inspired by [H264Naked](https://github.com/shi-yan/H264Naked). Done by compiling [h264bitstream](https://github.com/aizvorski/h264bitstream) into WebAssembly and building a simple UI on top of it. Output information for NAL units is taken from [H264Naked](https://github.com/shi-yan/H264Naked) at the moment. Also supports files of any size, just will take some time initially to load the file, but navigation throughout the stream should be seamless.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same question. I tried h264 analysis, but it only supports windows. So I made a similar tool with Qt to support different platforms.[Download H264Naked](https://github.com/shi-yan/H264Naked). This tool is essentially a wrapper around libh264bitstream

Comment: Thanks for the tool (H264Naked). How do I compile it though?

Comment: @mkuse Binaries for Linux and Mac are in the releases tab. https://github.com/shi-yan/H264Naked/releases

Comment: Tried to run it. "This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"". 

Should I install QT?